# What is the invisible unselectable entity on a supposedly empty layer?

Tags: layers

My scene has stuff on three layers.  The layer buttons show a dot on a fourth layer, one that to my knowledge contains nothing - no meshes, no cameras, no lights or anything.  If I have only that one layer active, and tap 'A' to select everything, nothing shows, just the usual grid and 3D cursor.  What the heck is existing in this layer that prevents it from being empty?

Comment: Just to be sure, you have pressed Alt + H to make sure nothing is hidden?

Comment: Can you attach the blend-file? Perhaps you have something hidden there.

Comment: Check your scene graph and see if anything is hidden in there.

Comment: When you delete a mesh in edit mode , its pivot point remains in object mode. Check your layer. Select all and press delete.

Comment: It's possible that whatever is hidden/invisible on that layer is also un-selectable. (selectability in the 3D view can be toggled in the Outliner by pressing the mouse icon)

Comment: Are you still having this problem? Have any of these suggestions worked? If not, can you please update the post to receive better help?

Comment: Yes, I tried Alt-H, and I looked at the Outliner for clues.  I'll attach the .blend file later; no time right now.

Answer (score 6):

Select the suspicious layer. In the **Outliner**, set the *Display Mode* to *Visible Layers*:

[image: The outliner, with display modes shown]

If there's anything there – hidden or not – you'll see it there.

If nothing appears, please upload your `.blend` file for further diagnosis.